# Concurrent transactions : reading data being modified

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency

Given this SQL transactional function (knowing "PK" means "Primary Key"):

```
1) READ a value from given PK (if exists)
2) DELETE row of given PK (if exists)
3) INSERT row for same PK
```

#### Questions

In a Postgres server, if two instances of that transactional function are ran concurrently for the same PK, what happens internally?

- Say transaction 1 (t1) has just finished executing step 2, when transaction 2 (t2) reaches step 1: will t2 read the value that was deleted by t1 because t1 hasn't committed yet?
- And then if t1 is still in between step 2 and 3, and t2 executes step 2: is a rollback initiated for t2?

##### Follow-up

If there are indeed concurrency problems, how exactly can such a function be made to work properly without resorting to table-locks?

It seems to me that a row-lock would be great, but my understanding is that they do not prevent reads from happening so the second function would still potentially read an erroneous value (for example, if the entry was deleted and not yet reinserted, then it would assume it shouldn't count it, when it fact it should instead be waiting on the new insertion).

Comment: You might find this useful https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html

Comment: Yeah, I started scratching my ahead over transaction isolation level. I'm thinking I could use [`SELECT FOR UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/explicit-locking.html) for the initial read. Or potentially `REPEATABLE READ` as the isolation level instead. I'm not quite sure how to decide which one is best (both in terms of correctness and performance). [This other answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/303308/241662) seems to suggest the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` would be a better approach? I'll have to dig a bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer to the first question

The second transaction can still read the value that the first transaction has deleted, because the first transaction has not committed yet and reading data requires no row lock.

Relevant [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html#XACT-READ-COMMITTED) (emphasis is mine):

> Read Committed is the **default isolation level in PostgreSQL**. When a transaction uses this isolation level, a SELECT query (without a FOR UPDATE/SHARE clause) **sees only data committed before the query began; it never sees either uncommitted data or changes committed during query execution by concurrent transactions**. In effect, a SELECT query sees a snapshot of the database as of the instant the query begins to run. However, SELECT does see the effects of previous updates executed within its own transaction, even though they are not yet committed. Also note that two successive SELECT commands can see different data, even though they are within a single transaction, if other transactions commit changes after the first SELECT starts and before the second SELECT starts.

### Answer to the second question

The delete in the second transaction will be blocked by the row lock taken by the first transaction, and it will hang until the first transaction finishes.

### Solutions

To avoid race conditions like that, either perform the first step using

```
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE
```

or use a higher [transaction isolation level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html) than `READ COMMITTED`.

Relevant [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/explicit-locking.html) (emphasis is mine):

> FOR UPDATE causes the rows retrieved by the SELECT statement to be locked as though for update. This prevents them from being locked, modified or deleted by other transactions until the current transaction ends. That is, **other transactions that attempt UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT FOR UPDATE, SELECT FOR NO KEY UPDATE, SELECT FOR SHARE or SELECT FOR KEY SHARE of these rows will be blocked until the current transaction ends**; conversely, SELECT FOR UPDATE will wait for a concurrent transaction that has run any of those commands on the same row, and will then lock and return the updated row (or no row, if the row was deleted). **Within a REPEATABLE READ or SERIALIZABLE transaction, however, an error will be thrown if a row to be locked has changed since the transaction started**. For further discussion see [Section 13.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/applevel-consistency.html).

Thus, the former solution will take a row lock and block the concurrent transaction early on, the latter will make one of the transactions fail.

Comment: Great answer. How should I decide between `REPEATABLE READ` transaction isolation level and `SELECT FOR UPDATE`? It seems like the former would be better for a "fail fast" type of scenario. All in all the main thing we need to optimize for is response time. Knowing there are also many calls which do the step 1 only (`READ a value from given PK (if exists)`). `SELECT FOR UPDATE` would slow down those reads, potentially leading to timeouts under high contention (>2000 requests per second, with timeout below 1 second because we need to ensure fast responses)?

Comment: If many calls will only `SELECT`, a `REPEATABLE READ` transaction may be the better choice, as it means less locking and more concurrency.

Comment: At the cost of some potential exceptions when the "only `SELECT`" happen while the described function is running, right?

Comment: Serialization errors (that require you to repeat the transaction) will never happen if you are only reading.